# Inline tags in kwic:summarize shown as spaces

Tags: lucene, xquery, exist-db

I'm trying to display some search results using an xquery on an eXist server like this:

```
kwic:summarize($doc//tei:text, <config width="60"/>
```

I have defined a lucene index in collection.xconf like this

```
<lucene>
    <text qname="tei:text">
        <inline qname="tei:ex"/>
    </text>
</lucene>
```

Now the search can find a text with ex tags such as:

```
th<ex>et</ex>tæ b<ex>re</ex>ff
```

But when it is displayed in the kwic search result list it is displayed as:

```
th et tæ b re ff
```

It should be displayed as:

```
thettæ breff
```

How do I make kwic:summarize not insert these spaces?

Comment: Which version of eXist? Have you tried adding this to your query's prolog? `declare boundary-space strip;` or `declare option exist:serialize "indent=no";`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both, but unfortunately it has no effect (both together and not together). The site is using eXists-db 2.1. I will try to upgrade in the near future, and write back here if it works.

Comment: I have upgraded to eXist-db 3.2, and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading the eXist-db 2.1 instance to eXist-db 3.2.